# Android Google Play Services on AVD

Tags: android, google-signin

I am trying to test my app for many devices, but in emulators, there are no google play services, thus I cannot check whether the google sign in is working for lower APIs (below 7.0)

Any chance I can try checking it?

Answer (score 0):

> but in emulators, there are no google play services,

That's not true, check the docs: https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup

Also, make sure you're using emulator with Google APIs.

[image]